# Can I Create a Zabbix Item which Tracks the CKSUM of a File with a Slightly Varying Filename?

Tags: configuration, zabbix

Using Zabbix v2.4 on RHEL 6.4

### Goal

I'd like to track the checksum of a file across multiple systems where the directory doesn't change, but the filename has very slight variations in it.  In our case, the filename contains a build number for the software, and we have multiple sites at different versions.  (Hence the difference in names.)

### Question and Catches

*Can I create a single template item which accounts for these varying file names using the built-in Regular Expressions support?*

- Can't modify the filenames to remove the build number.
- Don't have a lot of control over the agent configurations, so adding UserParameters would be a considerable effort.

Example file names:

- 12**3**4_file.jar
- 12**5**4_file.jar

### What I've Tried

Zabbix has built-in regular expression support, but I haven't been able to find a good example of its use in item keys.  The [Regular Expression page](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/regular_expressions) says

> In those cases where that may lead to misinterpretation when
>   referencing (for example, a comma in the parameter of an item
>   key) the whole reference may be put in quotes like this

which implies that they can be used in keys, but, perhaps, not the way I'd like to use them.

I defined a custom RE as "FileName" with the proper logical expressions to match my filenames (tests checked out just fine), and my key is as follows:

```
vfs.file.cksum[/path/to/file/@FileName]
```

But when I review the Agent logs, it says "check 'vfs.file.cksum[/path/to/file/@FileName]' is not supported" with "no such file or directory," so it doesn't look like the key is expanding/matching which means I probably misunderstood how to use custom RE's in keys (or they only work in certain key types).

Answer (score 1):

According to [item documentation](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/config/items/itemtypes/zabbix_agent), `vfs.file.cksum[]` accepts a file name as the first parameter (unlike, for instance, `logrt[]` item), so a regular expression will not work there.

One possible approach would be to use a [user macro](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/config/macros/usermacros) here and define the item as follows:

```
vfs.file.cksum[/path/to/file/12{$VERSION}4_file.jar]
```

Then define the appropriate `{$VERSION}` macro for each host.

Alternatively, you can use [low-level discovery](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/discovery/low_level_discovery) to discover the files you want, but that would involve writing a UserParameter, which you would rather avoid. Meanwhile, there is a feature request for a built-in file discovery at [ZBXNEXT-712](https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBXNEXT-712) that you can vote on.